# add path of controller in form->create in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

**firstCode**

```
 echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
'id' => 'form-login',
 'inputDefaults' => array(
    'label' => false,
    'div' => false,

 )
));
```

**Second Code**

```
echo $form->create('User', array('url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')));
```

sorry to ask this silly question.i want to merge second code into firstone ..as they are working fine independently.. i have tried many times but failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably mixing up the arrays. Should all be in one big array (as the `create()` method [only takes 2 arguments](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-forms)), like this:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
    'url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
    'id' => 'form-login',
    'inputDefaults' => array('label' => false, 'div' => false)
));
```

Comment: thank you for your answer..it is adding the parameters fine but form is not working ..actually what is happening is if i use your code then when i inspect my form elements it is showing this <input name="data[email]  but if i use my first code in which form successfully worked is showing this                        <input name="data[User][email]                                                  how can i add  this " data[User][email]" into your code..i dont know how this cakephp helper method works

Comment: thanks it works ... actually i was missing the model name .. so i have add explicitly like this ..... $this->form->input('User.email')